# Mesh deform a curve with shape keys

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves, shape-keys

How do I deform a curve or a mesh using the mesh deform modifiers and key frames. Basically, I'm trying to bind the curve to the mesh when the mesh at its Basis key. I then turn up the influence on another key(on the mesh). The curve does not deform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A curve is defined by a number of points and the connection between each point is then calculated. Any deform modifier on a curve can only move the points that define the curve, it cannot distort the curve in-between two curve points.

To get the benefits of a mesh deform modifier on a curve you need to be sure that the areas of the mesh that are deformed by shapekeys are surrounding a point in the curve.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. It's odd that the modifier is even available for the curve, since it doesn't work properly.